# Single java thread using excess system resources

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a server listener. It sits back and waits for data coming from the client and performs setting actions due to the nature of the data. But right now, after receiving the first data stream, it goes into a resource hog, the memory usage shoots up and the CPU usage is maxing out a single core.

1 - How can I fix this? How can I make it **listen** without all the resource hog, as you can see it is a really really small program.

2 - The client itself that sends these data streams, runs once. It starts up, connects to the server, sends the data and quits. While the server is still "on", if I retry running the client again, the server doesn't receive the data.

Server Code:

```
package mediaserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader br;

    public Main() throws IOException{
        ss = new ServerSocket(1111);
        s = ss.accept();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        new Thread(new runner()).start();
    }

    class runner implements Runnable{

        public void run(){
          while(true){
            try {
                String n = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(n);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
             finally{
                 try {
                       s.close();
                       ss.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }

             }
          }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Client Code

```
package mediaserver;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class test {
public static void main(String [] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException{
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1111);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
    bw.write("");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just press *Pause* in the debugger and check what it's doing.

Comment: This is what debuggers are for.  Time to learn one.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code is an infinite loop:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        String n = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(n);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

Once the client disconnects, the `BufferedReader` instance will encounter the end-of-file and `readLine` will return `null`. The loop then will continue to print `null` infinitely.

The fix it, check for `null`:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        String n = br.readLine();
        if (n == null)
            break;
        System.out.println(n);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the null fix. But the resource usage is still high.

Comment: Have you looked at it in the debugger?

Comment: Add some logging to the empty catch block or move it out of the while loop.

Comment: @Mob: Please add the additional code in the catch block. It could result in an infinite loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

The server never gets the data on additional run because ss.accept() is only called one time. You need to wrap this in a loop:

```
s = ss.accept();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
new Thread(new runner()).start();
```